# Issues assigning background color when anchor element highlighted

Tags: html, css

I've been trying to add a red background to the buttons on my navigation bar when they're being hovered over with the mouse. I can't seem to get it to appear, not sure what my issue is. I've watched multiple videos and just can't seem to get it properly. I'm using bootstrap 4 via codepen. Not very experienced with it, so not able to troubleshoot properly. Hoping someone can help figure out what exactly I'm doing wrong.

Here's the link to the pen: https://codepen.io/tazmancooks/pen/WzPROR

```
nav ul li a.active {background: #E2472F;color: #fff;border-radius: 6px;
```

Is the code that isn't taking into effect (given I've properly used it)

Answer (score 1):

Your current code in the codepen is the following:

```
nav ul li a.active a:hover {
```

This doesn't work because it's looking for a `a:hover` inside an `a.active`. I think instead you're looking for this:

```
nav ul li a.active,
nav ul li a:hover {
  /* insert styling */
]
```

Answer (score 1):

The code below can solve your problem.

```css
nav .logo {
  padding: 22px 20px;
  height: 80px;
  float: left;
  transition: .3s;
}

nav ul {
  list-style: none;
  float: right;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
}

nav ul il {
  list-style: none;
}

nav ul li a {
  line-height: 80px;
  color: #151515;
  padding: 12px 30px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  transition: .3s;
  
}

nav ul li a:focus {
  outline: none;
}

nav ul li a.active,
nav ul li a:hover {
  background: #E2472F;
  color: #222;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <div class="logo">Logo</div>
   <ul>
     <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
   </ul>  
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have not assigned background color for `:hover` Try this code.

```
nav ul li a:hover {
  background: #E2472F;
  color: #ffffff;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've posted the Code pen Link. Which you can check and i think it will help you to solve the Problem.

```css
nav .logo {
  padding: 22px 20px;
  height: 80px;
  float: left;
  transition: .3s;}

nav ul {
  list-style: none;
  float: right;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex; }

nav ul li a {
  line-height: 80px;
  color: #151515;
  padding: 12px 30px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  transition: .3s;}

nav ul li a:hover {
  background: #E2472F;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 6px;}
```

```html
<nav>
  <div class="logo">Logo</div>
   <ul>
     <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
   </ul>  
</nav>
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/qogxYV

Comment: The code pen link and the fiddle is attached above as per your requirements...please check it and update me. Thank you. Good Luck!!!

Comment: If you got desired solution from my answer, then please accept it.